# Why Telnet protocol uses only 1 port on server while FTP uses 2 ports

Tags: networking, ftp, telnet, protocol

I got this question in a job interview and I had no idea what to answer.
Can someone please help me understand it?

Why does telnet protocol use only 1 port while the FTP protocol uses 2 ports on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already noted, telnet uses only 1 port as it's interactive/terminal usage. Ftp set's up two communication channels - control and data. This means that the data channel is independent from control [interactive] comms. Moreover, control channel uses Telnet proto ([RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt)):

```
The Relationship between FTP and Telnet:

         The FTP uses the Telnet protocol on the control connection.
```

Here is nice example how out of bound signaling (separate channels) could be used to optimize communication paths (also from [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt))):

> In another situation a user might wish to transfer files between
>         two hosts, neither of which is a local host. The user sets up
>         control connections to the two servers and then arranges for a
>         data connection between them.  In this manner, control information
>         is
>    passed to the user-PI but data is transferred between the
>         server data transfer processes.  Following is a model of this
>         server-server interaction.

```
                Control     ------------   Control
                ---------->| User-FTP |<-----------
                |          | User-PI  |           |
                |          |   "C"    |           |
                V          ------------           V
        --------------                        --------------
        | Server-FTP |   Data Connection      | Server-FTP |
        |    "A"     |<---------------------->|    "B"     |
        -------------- Port (A)      Port (B) --------------
```

Answer (score 1):

FTP uses a command channel and a data channel, hence two connections are needed.
Telnet connects to exactly one port - the one you tell it to.

See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Communication_and_data_transfer) on the Wikipedia page for more info

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please tell me why telnet uses only 1 port ? while ftp uses 2 ports ?

Answer (score 1):

Telnet only uses one port because it only establishes one bidrectional stream of data between the client and the server: The data from client's keyboard (or stdin) to server, and the data from server to client's screen (or stdout). There is no need for it to ever send any "control" or "status" information. Your client connects to the telnet server, and from then on telnet emulates a three-wire (Tx data, Rx data, and ground) cable between a computer's serial port and a serial terminal. Your client has no way to send any commands or other "out of band" info to the telnet server after that, nor any need to - so there is no need for a separate comm channel, which is what a secodnd port would provide.  The only "control information" that is ever passed is when the client disconnects - and disconnection notification is handled automatically by TCP.

FTP needs to exchange both data and a command-and-response protocol between client and server. The designers chose to use different ports for these two functions. This makes some aspects of the programming easier, particularly with older operating systems that didn't support multithreading or asynchronous I/O as well. For example, you can send or receive control and status info while you're receiving or sending file data, and from the program's point of view, the "control" stream doesn't have to wait for a buffer to complete on the "data" stream before sending or receiving its own buffer.

However! The designers of ftp could have done it differently. They could have used just a single port. They could have added a byte or so to the front of each chunk of file data, or command, or response, that would tell the other end "this is a data chunk" or "this goes to the command/response path". This does make the programming a little more difficult, and it does preclude independent reads and writes to the two streams. But the basic functions of ftp *could* have been done with just one port.

And telnet could have used a second port - though with telnet's limited functionality, I can't imagine what for. Maybe one port for each direction... or maybe to cleanly implement sending a "break".

So one ultimately valid, but likely unhelpful, answer is: "because the people who wrote them implemented that way."

Answer (score -2):

[Ftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp) protocol use 2 ports 20 and 21, port 20 is for Control and port 21 for Data, and [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) only use port 23 to make interactions with a terminal.

Comment: dont telnet have a control and data port ??

Comment: May i know why telnet uses only 23 ? where ftp uses 20 and 21 ? thank you

Comment: Telnet is a protocol used to have an terminal-interaction in a host, ftp open a terminal and u can interact with it from port 20 and if u want tx or rx data it haves another port, port 21